# Isometries and Symmetries of the set $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-numbers, integers, symmetry, isometry, orthogonal-matrices

> (a) Find all translations that are symmetries of $\mathbb{Z}^2$
>
> (b) Find all isometries in $GO_2$ that are symmetries of $\mathbb{Z}^2$

My solutions:

(a) Firstly, we define a translation $T_z(x) = x + z$. Now, we know that all translations are isometries. All we need now is to find translations for which $T_z(\mathbb{Z}^2) = \mathbb{Z}^2$ to make it a symmetry. We see that this is true for all $z \in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Thus, we can conclude that all translations that are symmetries of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are translations defined as follows: $T_z(x) =$ {$x + z | x,z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 $}.

(b) So, I know that $GO_2 = $ {$x \rightarrow Ux |$ where $U$ is an orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrix}. Therefore, I make the general claim that all isometries of $GO_2$ that are symmetries of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are any function $F \in GO_2$ where $F(x) = Ux$ with $U$ as a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix and $x, UX \in \mathbb{Z}^2$

I feel like I am not making arguments that are strong enough in my answers. Since I am still new to isometries and symmetries, I find it a bit challenging to apply more complex topics to provide evidence for my thinking.

If anyone is able to help point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your claims are correct. However, your proof of them is not very thorough: in (a) you only proved that $z\in \mathbb{Z}^2$ is a sufficient condition, not that it is necessary. A more complete proof could use the fact that a necessary condition for $T_z$ to be a simmetry is $T_z((0,0))\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. When does this happen?

Comment: For (b), maybe you could use the fact that, to be an isometry, $F$ has to satisfy $F(e_1)\in \mathbb{Z}^2; F(e_2)\in \mathbb{Z}^2; F^{-1}(e_1)\in \mathbb{Z}^2; F^{-1}(e_2)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. What does this tell you?